# PHP replace token in html email variable before sending

Tags: php, token

I have an email that I send out to subscribers of my site. I do this by getting the subscriber list from my database and the looping through the array and sending one email at a time... I know there is a way to send all at once but this is why I do it this way and the bit I need help with...

The HTML email contains 2 tokens:

`{name}` and `{date}`

What i need to do is insert the date in the HTML email replacing the `{date}` token and insert the name replacing the `{name}` for each email send (as the name is always different).

This is what I have:

```
        $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_newsletter WHERE `id` IN ( $userIds )");
        for($i = 0, $size = sizeof($result); $i < $size; ++$i){
          add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html";'));
          $to .= $result[$i]->name.'<'.$result[$i]->email.'>';
          $mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject , $message, $headers);
        }
```

as you can see above I have two variables from the database:

`$result[$i]->name`

`$result[$i]->email`

and `$message` is the HTML email body that has the 2 tokens that needs to be replaced.

so.... everything is working as expected for the looping and sending I just need some help with how I do the token replace for `{name}` and `{date}`.

Any help with this will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done with PHP's `str_replace` function, [docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
...
$message = str_replace('{name}', $result[$i]->name, $message);
$message = str_replace('{date}', date('Y/m/d H:i:s'), $message);  // Or your preferred date format

$mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject , $message, $headers);
```

Note that if you know there will only be a single instance of `{name}` and/or `{date}` you can pass a 4th parameter `$count` to `str_replace` and it will quit after replacing the first match.

Cheers

Comment: ok.. @Madbreaks .. I have an issue that it sends all emails with only the first name in the loop. any ideas around that? I geuss when it loops through again it has the first name instance and no loger the token.

Comment: nevermind.. I did this: `for($i = 0, $size = sizeof($result); $i < $size; ++$i){
  
  $newMessage = $message;
  $newMessage = str_replace('{name}', $result[$i]->name, $newMessage);
  $newMessage = str_replace('{date}', date('F j, Y'), $newMessage);
  
  add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html";'));
  
  $to .= $result[$i]->name.'<'.$result[$i]->email.'>';
  $mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject , $newMessage, $headers);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = str_replace('{name}',$result[$i]->name,$message);
$message = str_replace('{date}',date('Y/m/d H:i:s'),$message);
```

---

```
str_replace('{name}',$result[$i]->name);
str_replace('{date}',date('Y/m/d H:i:s'));
```